# Moving to a SaaS architecture from on-premises

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, saas

Our current solution is an ASP.NET WebApi server and various client apps which run:

1. Our on-premises: Server and web clients run in our premises. The customer databases are also found here. The main app (WinForms) is installed on the customer's users pc's.
2. Customer on-premises. Server, database and main app (WinForms) are available within the customer infrastructure. Web clients are still located in our premises.

The projects / apps:

1. Database: SQL Server database, non multi-tenant, ie. database per tenant.
2. Server: ASP.NET Core WebApi, non multi-tenant. Connects to different local customer databases. Users might be local AD users or users created in the authorization server (3).
3. Authorization Server: ASP.NET MVC app that uses OpenId to authenticate and authorize uses. Used by the server (2) and clients below.
4. Main client app: WinForms app that connects to a server (2).
5. Dashboard apps: Blazor server-side apps, multi-tenant. Connect to a server (2) using host name strategy.
6. Web apps: Mixture of ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core apps, non multi-tenant

We would like to move to a SaaS architecture. We will choose database per tenant to avoid noisy neighbor problems and data contamination, as well as security.

The main development work will be development a web-app to replace the main WinForms app.In this case, I see to possibile solutions:

1. Expand the server (2) to add razor pages. Additionally, the server must become multi-tenant.
2. Create a web app. the current WinForms app is huge. However, user size is in the low to mid 1000.

In this situation what would be the most practicable solution for the main client app? Blazor Server-side or ASP.NET Core Razor pages?

Any other solutions that might be considered?

Comment: if the winforms app is already going through an api for everything (not contacting db directly), and the users are content with it, what's the benefit in reimplementing it as a web app?

Comment: then you don't have to maintain the winforms app on client pc-s + it becomes cross-platform

Comment: I would suggest developing and deploying your Client Web app as a separate App.  This allows betters separation of concerns, but more important is better and independent scalability.